# How to create a notebook with a properly formatted expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend, mathematical-expressions

I have a Mathematica expression generated by another program, which I would like to open in a notebook, properly formatted.  For instance, the other program generates this:

```
Plot[{Exp[x],Interpolation[Table[{k/5,Exp[(k-1/2)/5]},{k,0,5}],
InterpolationOrder->0][x]},{x,0,1},Filling->{1->{{2},{Yellow,Orange}}},
PlotLabel->Style["Formatting",Blue,FontFamily->"Courier"]]
```

The text is written into a file, crudely suffixed ".nb", and launched, and the expression opens in a notebook without formatting.  To achieve formatting, writing a file manually with BoxData seems impractical.

The file is actually being launched from .Net using Process.Start("filename.nb"), but a command line launch seems equally problematic.

Comment: Just curious ... What program are you using to generate that?

Comment: @ belisarius - using .Net to build a function with numerous parameters & arguments. It's not actually a plot function like the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I adopted.  Thanks for all the help.

The main step of the solution is to format the command via the kernel:-

```
FullForm[ToBoxes[
  Defer[Plot[{Exp[x], 
     Interpolation[Table[{k/5, Exp[(k - 1/2)/5]}, {k, 0, 5}], 
       InterpolationOrder -> 0][x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Yellow, Orange}}}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style["Formatting", Blue, FontFamily -> "Courier"]]]]]
```

Then the formatted data is encapsulated to create a notebook:-

```
Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[

... ( inserted box-formatted output ) ...

], "Input"]
},
WindowSize->{615, 750},
WindowMargins->{{328, Automatic}, {Automatic, 76}},
StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"
]
```

This is written to a file, suffixed ".nb".  All fine and dandy.

This approach works well for multi-statement blocks of code, but some additional processing was included to format a single function call of the form Function[expression, options] to add a line-break before each option.  Here is the C# code used to produce both types of output:-

```
public static class MathematicaHelpers
{
    public static string CreateNotebook(string mathCommand, string fileLocation, MathKernel kernel, bool addNewLines)
    {
        if (addNewLines) {
            mathCommand = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "Module[{boxoutput,b2},boxoutput=FullForm[ToBoxes[Defer[", mathCommand, "]]];b2=boxoutput[[1,1,3,1]];boxoutput[[1,1,3,1]]=Join[Flatten[Riffle[Partition[b2,2],\"\\[IndentingNewLine]\"],1],{\"\\[IndentingNewLine]\",Last[b2]}];boxoutput]");
        } else {
            mathCommand = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "FullForm[ToBoxes[Defer[", mathCommand, "]]]");
        }
        fileLocation = Path.ChangeExtension(fileLocation, ".nb");

        mathCommand = ComputeMathCommand(mathCommand, kernel);
        mathCommand = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[", mathCommand,
                                    "], \"Input\"]},WindowSize->{615, 750}, WindowMargins->{{328, Automatic}, {Automatic, 76}},StyleDefinitions->\"Default.nb\"]");

        File.WriteAllText(fileLocation, mathCommand);
        return fileLocation;
    }                             

    private static string ComputeMathCommand(string command, MathKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Compute(command);
        return kernel.Result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
Export["C:\\Temp\\formatTest1.nb", 
   ToExpression[Import["C:\\Temp\\formatTest.nb", "Text"], InputForm, MakeBoxes]]
```

I tested it and it seems to work (importing from the plain file, exporting to the one you will then open). This does create explicit boxes, but with a very little effort on the user's side. I did not test, but you should be able to run this code in the script mode, from the command line.

**EDIT**

To test from within Mathematica, you can use e.g.

```
Export["C:\\Temp\\formatTest.nb", 
  ToString@HoldForm@FullForm@
    Plot[{Exp[x],Interpolation[Table[{k/5, Exp[(k - 1/2)/5]}, {k, 0, 5}],
    InterpolationOrder -> 0][x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Yellow, Orange}}},
    PlotLabel -> Style["Formatting", Blue, FontFamily -> "Courier"]], 
  "Text"]
```

before running the code above.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting to see use of ToExpression with MakeBoxes. I can confirm it works, e.g. FullForm[ToExpression[ToString[HoldForm[FullForm[expression]]], 
   InputForm, MakeBoxes]] == FullForm[ToBoxes[Defer[expression]]]

Comment: @Chris I guess I subconsciously dislike `Defer`, probably because I don't know of a situation where its functionality can not be achieved in other, more transparent ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following wrapping:

```
nb = CreateWindow[
     DocumentNotebook[{
       Plot[{Exp[x], 
       Interpolation[Table[{k/5, Exp[(k - 1/2)/5]}, {k, 0, 5}], 
       InterpolationOrder -> 0][x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
       Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Yellow, Orange}}}, 
       PlotLabel -> 
       Style["Formatting", Blue, FontFamily -> "Courier"]]
     }]]
```

then commands NotebookSave and NotebookClose can be used to save and close the thing ;)

Comment: This is a little closer to what I'm looking for, but despite trying I can't execute it from a command line: CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer[Plot[{Exp[x],Interpolation[Table[{k/5,Exp[(k-1/2)/5]},{k,0,5}],InterpolationOrder->0][x]},{x,0,1},Filling->{1->{{2},{Yellow,Orange}}},PlotLabel->Style["Formatting",Blue,FontFamily->"Courier"]]],"Input"]]

Comment: @Chris You need to wrap your code in Developer`UseFrontEnd, again I mean use `UseFrontEnd` in `Developer` context.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you create the `BoxData` expressions explicitly there is no way to format your expression without actually invoking at least the Mathematica FrontEnd.

The closest I can think of is that you add the following:

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, EvaluationCell]; 
FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
                 "SelectionConvert", "StandardForm"]}]; 
Plot[{Exp[x], Interpolation[Table[{k/5, Exp[(1/5)*(k - 1/2)]}, {k, 0, 5}], 
                InterpolationOrder -> 0][x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Yellow, Orange}}}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Formatting", Blue, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
  Evaluated -> True]
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, GeneratedCell];
```

which automatically formats the `Plot` command when the cell is evaluated.
(BTW: You probably should either add `Evaluate` in front of the list or add the (not-so-well documented) `Evaluate->True` option.

Comment: `ToBoxes` allows to convert expressions to `BoxForms` using only the kernel.

Comment: @ Alexey - thanks. I'm getting somewhere with the Kernel output from this: ToBoxes[Defer[
Plot[{Exp[x],Interpolation[Table[{k/5,Exp[(k-1/2)/5]},{k,0,5}],
InterpolationOrder->0][x]},{x,0,1},Filling->{1->{{2},{Yellow,Orange}}},
PlotLabel->Style["Formatting",Blue,FontFamily->"Courier"]]
]]