# The command "nb = NotebookCreate[]" fails within Mathematica?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

If I open a notebook in Mathematica, and type "nb=NotebookCreate[]", it creates a new notebook window, as expected.

However, if I try the same command from within C#, it fails, and doesn't open a new notebook window:

```
IKernelLink ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();
string cmd = @"nb = NotebookCreate[]";
string result = ml.EvaluateToOutputForm(cmd, 0);

// result is now "$Failed".
```

Note that if I pass in "2+2", it returns "4", which proves the link to the Mathematica kernel is working perfectly well.

Comment: p.s. One of the reasons why it would be amazing to get this working is so I could pump debugging information from my C# console app into an interactive workbook in Mathematica, particularly interactive 3-D graphs.

Comment: Notebook created directly from box data using C# in this example, might be of some use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7321479/879601

Comment: You might get a better response if you have this migrated to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com -- flag it for moderator attention and request this if you choose.

Comment: Another link that could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8279901/879601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears as if this is impossible for Mathematica v8 (and I don't think much has changed in v9).

From what I understand, when you access the Mathematica kernel from C#, this does not allow access to the Notebook classes, which are part of the GUI.

Comment: Are you sure it is impossible? `NotebookCreate[]` requires `$FrontEnd` to be defined (that is the FrontEnd must be launched and connected to the kernel). I suspect that you simply have not connected the FrontEnd. Try to evaluate `NotebookCreate[]` in pure MathKernel session - you will get `$Failed` as expected.